# Hibernate does not supporting TIMESTAMPDIFF for oracle

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Hibernate does not support TIMESTAMPDIFF for Oracle

It is giving an error in Oracle but running very fine in MySql

```
**Query** :select app from Application app where app.id not in ( select aml.referenceId from AuditMailLog aml  where app.id = aml.referenceId and aml.event = 'application_expiry_reminder' and aml.referenceTableName = 'application' ) and TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, created_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) >= 30 and status in (0,1)
```

Can anybody tell me what could be the alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Oracle itself does not support the `timestampdiff()` function.

`timestampdiff()` is available in many databases, but not Oracle, DB2, nor Postgres.

Even the [JDBC specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1558082951_88ee3b4bcf95b0e57a3019fb1a77d342) lists `timestampdiff()` among the functions it strongly advocates that a JDBC driver should support via an escape syntax i.e. `{fn timestampdiff(x,y,z)}` but unfortunately support for those functions is in practice extremely patchy.

The way to approach this problem in Oracle is to use the `-` operator to subtract timestamps, producing an interval, and then use the `extract()` function to pick apart its fields.

There is more information here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#BABBICGH

Answer (score -1):

You can use `DetachedCriteria` for your query and `Restrictions.sqlRestriction` for SQL functions.